# I can't find the file "font5x5.py"

Tags: python, led, script

I have a serious problem, I've intalled [this](https://github.com/pimoroni/scroll-phat-hd) But in my RPi, I can't find and edit the "font5x5.py". But when I import it with another script, it work. Can you please help a french beginer ??

Comment: try this sudo find / -name font5x5.py

Comment: However, after looking at the repo https://github.com/pimoroni/scroll-phat-hd/tree/master/tools are you sure that is the filename you are looking for

Comment: I tried the find command, but i can't found it
Yes i'm looking for the .py not the png one

Comment: If you look at my second comment that does not appear to be the correct filename. There is mkfont-5x5.py and 5x5-font.png

Comment: The mkfont is defining how the font must be read, but I want to change the font itself